# Dedicate every element in a list to a variable

Tags: python, list

So let's say we have the lists `a = [1,2,3,4]` and `s = ["q", "w", "e", "r"]`.
I want to dedicate every element in `s` a value in `a`, so that `print(w)` prints `2` and so on. You could write

```
for u in range(0, len(a)):
   s[u] = a[u]
```

But here `print(w)` makes no sense and we get an error.

Comment: use a `dict` to map elements as you want!

Answer (score 2):

A `dict` does exactly this:

```
In [1261]: d = dict(zip(s, a))

In [1262]: d
Out[1262]: {'e': 3, 'q': 1, 'r': 4, 'w': 2}
```

To get the value associated with `e`, simply use `dict indexing`:

```
In [1263]: d['e']
Out[1263]: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution does exactly what you have specified, using the built-in [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function. However, you should **never ever ever use it**! It is hideously unsafe, and I am only posting it for completeness' sake. Use the solution after it instead.

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    exec(s[i] + "=" + str(a[i]))
```

What you **should** do is use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
myDictionary = dict(zip(s, a))
```

What this does is it matches each element of the lists `s` and `a` into key-value pairs in a dictionary by their index (meaning that they are matched based on their order).

And then you can do:

```
>>> print(myDictionary["w"])
2
```